# Get Facebook Warnings While Posting Via app ( Asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've build a web app to post on my pages via page identity.
is there any method/procedure to get any kind of warnings that appear while posting images/link on my pages, like when posting regular we get captcha or other pop up messages regarding anything we post, but we don't get this when doing so via app. so is there anything that can be used to get that on app?

i use this code to post on fb

```
 FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(PageAccessToken);
 dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
 parameters.message = txtTitle.Text;
 parameters.link = strLink;
 var PostID = client.Post("/" + PageId + "/feed", parameters);
```

Now When posting if there's any captcha or another messages (Warning) while posting, i wanna see it on app??

Let Me Be Clear a Little:
When u post too many posts on a page( Continuously), facebook shows captcha warnings every few posts 5-10. And When u reach a critical limit, facebook again shows captcha with warning message "You are misusing this feature", and if you continuously keep posting, fb will block u from posting. now when u post these posts via app, facebook keeps on posting without warnings/captcha's. so post on page manually=captcha popups and warning messages. post via app=no captcha/warning messages.
i want to read those messages on my app so i know if there's any warning or captcha message is shown(but ignored due to posting via app).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you make a call:

```
client.Post("/" + PageId + "/feed", parameters);
```

You get a JSON in response. I think `var PostID` is mis-leading. You get  a JSON in reponse.

If the posting is **success**, you get the response as-

```
{
    "id": "XXXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYYYY"
}
```

If posting fails, you get the response as-

```
{
    error:
      { 
         "message": " ........ ",
         "code": XXX,
         "type": "......"
      }
}
```

So you can always check for the `error` in the response and handle it appropriately.

Comment: It's true that i get the jason response which only includes the ID of post.

Comment: So what's the problem now?

Comment: If successful i get the Jason response which has the id of post, but
when the error occurs the function fb.post gives exception and i know that its failed to post(which means something terrible has already happened.
"Read last paragraph of my question"
so by posting via app, fb by default suppressing all warnings and captcha.
so by the time i get the error which will not be warning "u are misusing the feature", it will be 
"cannot post your message, you've been blocked from using this feature" i will already be blocked.
i need some-way to get those warnings which warn me before i get blocked.